# How do I get manage the data in the slider dynamically and efficiently

Tags: javascript, html, css, carousel, swiper.js

I created slider which works on dynamic data but the issue is I'm fetching all the data at the same time which is very inefficient. What I want is the same effect that I currently have but on first render only needed data should fetched and when a slide is clicked the required data should be fetched and rendered.
This is the current [Result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/19dfuzlXekU08tBHn5SebflKFgxuga98L/view?usp=sharing)

```
   <div class="container">

        <div class="slide">

        </div>

       


    </div>
```

JS functionality for sliding the divs

```
 const slideContainer = document.querySelector('.slide');
            fetch('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all')
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                // Create HTML elements based on the fetched data
                
                data.forEach(country => {
                    const item = document.createElement('div');
                    item.classList.add('item');
                    
                    // Customize the content based on your data structure
                    item.innerHTML = `
                        <div class="item-wrapper">
                            <img src="${country.flags.svg}" alt="${country.name.common}">
                            <div class="content">
                                <div class="sub-name">${country.name.common}</div>
                                <div class="name">${country.region}</div>
                                <button>See More</button>
                                <div class="des">Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab, eum!</div>
                                <div class="icon-wrapper">
                                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="svg-icons">
                                      <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M17.593 3.322c1.1.128 1.907 1.077 1.907 2.185V21L12 17.25 4.5 21V5.507c0-1.108.806-2.057 1.907-2.185a48.507 48.507 0 0 1 11.186 0Z" />
                                    </svg>
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="svg-icons">
                                      <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M21 8.25c0-2.485-2.099-4.5-4.688-4.5-1.935 0-3.597 1.126-4.312 2.733-.715-1.607-2.377-2.733-4.313-2.733C5.1 3.75 3 5.765 3 8.25c0 7.22 9 12 9 12s9-4.78 9-12Z" />
                                    </svg>
                                    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="svg-icons">
                                      <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M7.217 10.907a2.25 2.25 0 1 0 0 2.186m0-2.186c.18.324.283.696.283 1.093s-.103.77-.283 1.093m0-2.186 9.566-5.314m-9.566 7.5 9.566 5.314m0 0a2.25 2.25 0 1 0 3.935 2.186 2.25 2.25 0 0 0-3.935-2.186Zm0-12.814a2.25 2.25 0 1 0 3.933-2.185 2.25 2.25 0 0 0-3.933 2.185Z" />
                                    </svg>
                                    
                              </div>
                              <button class="view-btn">
                                  <span>ver pedra</span>
                                  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" >
                                      <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="m4.5 19.5 15-15m0 0H8.25m11.25 0v11.25" />
                                    </svg>
                                    </button>
                            </div>
                            <p class="unfocus-names">${country.region}</p>
                        </div>
                    `;
    
                    // Append the item to the slide container
                    item.addEventListener("click", () => {
                        const items = [...document.querySelectorAll('.item')];
                        const idx = items.indexOf(item);
                        slideContainer.append(...items.slice(0, idx-1));
                      });
                    slideContainer.appendChild(item);
                });
            })
            .catch(error => console.error('Error fetching data:', error));
```

Stylesheet

```
 body {
            background: #eaeaea;
            width: 100vw;
            height: 100vh;
            overflow: hidden;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            margin: auto;
        }

        .container {

            transform: translate(-85%, -5%);
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            background: #f5f5f5;
            margin-top: 20px;
            padding: 120px;

        }


        .container .slide .item {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
            left: 80%;
            transform: translate(290%, -50%);
            border-radius: 20px;
            background-position: 50% 50%;
            border-radius: 0;
            background-size: cover;
            display: inline-block;
            transition: 0.5s;
            transform-style: preserve-3d;

        }

        .container .slide .item .item-wrapper {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            display: relative;
        }

        .container .slide .item img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            position: relative;
            z-index: 2;
            object-fit: cover;
            object-position: center;
        }




        .slide .item:nth-child(1),
        .slide .item:nth-child(2) {
            top: 0;
            left: 0;
            transform: translate(0, 0);
            border-radius: 0;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        }

        .slide .item:nth-child(1) .item-wrapper p,
        .slide .item:nth-child(2) .item-wrapper p {
            display: none;
        }

        .slide .item .item-wrapper p {
            text-align: center;
        }



        .slide .item:nth-child(3) {
            left: 150%;
        }

        .slide .item:nth-child(4) {
            left: calc(150% + 120px);
        }

        .slide .item:nth-child(5) {
            left: calc(150% + 240px);
        }

        /* here n = 0, 1, 2, 3,... */
        .slide .item:nth-child(n + 6) {
            left: calc(150% + 360px);
            opacity: 0;
        }



        .item .content {
            transform: translateZ(-10px);
            position: absolute;
            top: 20%;
            right: 200px;
            width: 300px;
            text-align: left;
            color: black;
            transform: translate(0, -50%);
            font-family: system-ui;
            display: none;
            animation: animate 1s ease-in-out 1 forwards;
        }


        .slide .item:nth-child(2) .content {
            display: block;
        }




        .content .sub-name {
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: semibold;
            text-transform: uppercase;
        }

        .content .name {
            font-size: 40px;
            font-weight: bold;

        }

        .content .des {
            margin-top: 10px;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            font-size: 22px;
        }

        .content button {
            padding: 5px 20px;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            border-radius: 50px;
            border: 1px solid rgb(216, 216, 216);
            color: #ababab;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-style: normal;

        }


        @keyframes animate {
            0% {
                opacity: 0;
                transform: translate(0, 0);

            }

            40% {
                opacity: 0;
                transform: translate(0, 0);
            }

            100% {
                opacity: 100;
                transform: translate(650px);

            }
        }

        .icon-wrapper {
            margin: 30px auto;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            gap: 10px;
        }

        .svg-icons {
            width: 28px;
        }

        .button {
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            position: absolute;
            bottom: 20px;
        }

        .button button {
            width: 40px;
            height: 35px;
            border-radius: 8px;
            border: none;
            cursor: pointer;
            margin: 0 5px;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            transition: 0.3s;
        }

        .button button:hover {
            background: #ababab;
            color: #fff;
        }

        .view-btn {
            margin-top: 70px;
            border-color: black !important;
            color: black !important;
            width: 150px;
            height: 35px;
            border-radius: 0 !important;
            font-size: 14px !important;
            text-transform: uppercase;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .view-btn svg {
            width: 12px;
        }

        .swiper {
            display: none;
        }

        .prev-btn,
        .next-btn {
            display: none;
        }
```